# File not found from Dockerfile, docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have these codes in my Dockerfile.

```
FROM python:3

# Create user named "airport".
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" airport

# Login as the newly created "airport" user.
RUN su - airport

# Change working directory.
WORKDIR /home/airport/mount_point/

# Install Python packages at system-wide level.
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make sure to migrate all static files to the root of the project.
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# This utility.sh script is used to reset the project environment. This includes
# removing unecessary .pyc and __pycache__ folders. This is optional and not
# necessary, I just prefer to have my environment clean before Docking.
RUN utility_scripts/utility.sh
```

When I called `docker-compose build` it returns `/bin/sh: 1: requirements.txt: not found`. Despite I have load the necessary volume in my docker-compose.yml. I am sure that requirements.txt is in `./`

```
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    command: /home/airport/mount_point/start_web.sh
    container_name: django_airport
    expose:
      - "8080"
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/airport/mount_point/
      - ./timezone:/etc/timezone
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Before running `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt`, you need to add the requirements.txt file to the image.

```
...
ADD requirements.txt requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

For a sample on how to dockerize a django application, check https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/ . You need to add the requirements.txt and the code to the image.

Comment: Can I mount a volume instead? Because I have `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` that will work on my Django project. I tried to use `VOLUME ["./"]` but it gave me, `container_linux.go:265: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:368: container init caused \"apparmor failed to apply profile: no such file or directory\"` instead. Additionally will the `ADD`ed requirements.txt persist after container setup?

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll mounting a volume will no work in your case since thet pip install command will run when building the image, and volumes are mounted when running the image. You need to add your project sources inside the docker file, otherwise they will not be available in the image and the build will fail

Comment: @yamenk Ah yep, you are right. My comment is removed. Since you are building the app in the container and requirements.txt is, well, required,  it needs to be in there from the start.

Comment: @AndrewGraham-Yooll updated answer with useful link https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/